# On android browser, the layout of the mobiscroll control is not correct if text size is set to large, particularly in clickpick

Tags: android, layout, text, size, mobiscroll

To reproduce: on an android device, go to mobiscroll demo (in the default browser), set text size to larger or large and refresh the screen.

Does anyone know if this can be fixed via a setting or something or is this a bug?